# Weak topology generated by the collection of functions from $X$ to itself that contains the identity function contains any topology

Tags: general-topology

Justify the following statement: If $(X,T)$ is a topological space and $F$ is a collection of functions from $X$ to itself that contains the identity function, then the weak topology on $X$ generated by $F$ contains $T$.

I have been told this statement is true, but I am not sure why, any help is appreciated! Thanks a lot!

Comment: It doesn't make sense to include the identity function in the collection $F$ : $F$ must consist of set maps $f_i:X\to Y_i$ where each $Y_i$ is already endowed with a topology. Then the weak (or initial) topology on $Y$ is the coarsest topology rendering all maps $f_i$ continuous.

Comment: thanks for commenting. I am sure the original statement does include the identity function in $F$, I am not sure if there is a typo or not.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat: $X$ already has a topology $T$.

Comment: @Jose27 Right, I misread the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of weak topology says that the open sets (technically a subbase, but this doesn't cause problems here) are precisely those of the form $f^{-1}(A)$ for some open (with respect to $T$) $A$ and function $f\in F$. If $f= id_X$ then $f^{-1}(A)=A$ and so every open $A$ in $T$ is open in the weak topology induced by $F$.