# The weak topology for $\mathbb{R}$ generated by such functions

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Well I am working with some topology exercises, but I am not sure about my idea. So, the task is to describe the topology for $\mathbb{R}$ generated by such functions

---

CASE 1. The set of all functions continuous with respect to the usual topology

CASE 2. The family of consisting only of the identity map on $\mathbb{R}$.

---

Well, I think the weak topology would be the usual topology in both case. I'm pretty sure with the case 2 but I am not sure in case 1. 
Can I get any ideas??

Thanks

Comment: By weak topology generated by a set of functions you mean the topology which is sometimes also called [initial topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_topology)? Perhaps it could be clarified in the question. (Not everybody is familiar with the terminology.) If it is this, then perhaps linking to the Wikipedia article would be sufficient to make the question clearer. (Adding the source of those exercises you're working in might be useful, too.)

Comment: There is another unclear point. (Are you sure you copied this part correctly?) How should "The set of all functions continuous with respect to the usual topology" be understood? If you mean all continuous functions $\mathbb R\to X$, where $X$ can be arbitrary topological space, then it is not a set, but a proper class. If you mean only functions $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, then you should specify that you only mean real functions.

Comment: sorry with the confusion.  The actual exercise was to 'describe the weak topology for R generated by each of the followings'

Comment: This question seems to be related: [Weak topology generated by the collection of functions from $X$ to itself that contains the identity function contains any topology](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1193217),

Answer (score 1):

1. For any completely regular space $X$, the initial topology wrt real-valued continuous functions on $X$, is that same topology $X$. It's the motivation for completely regular spaces in the first place: these are the spaces where real-valued continuous functions describe the topology.
2. For any space $X$ the initial topology wrt the identity map on $X$ is the indiscrete topology (as all topologies on $X$ will make the identity continuous, we are left to consider the minimal topology on $X$). But if we are looking for the coarsest topology on $X$ that makes the identity from $X$ to $(X, \mathcal{T})$ continuous, it is $\mathcal{T}$ again, clearly.

Comment: I might be missing something, but I would expect initial topology for $id_X \colon X \to (X,\tau)$ be $\tau$. Certainly, if $\tau$ is not indiscrete, then $id_X \colon (X,\tau_{ind}) \to (X,\tau)$ is not continuous. (Basically something along this lines is also mentioned here: [Weak topology generated by the collection of functions from $X$ to itself that contains the identity function contains any topology](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1193217).)

Comment: @MartinSleziak if $X$ in the codomain is supposed to have the original topology, then you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\mathbb R_T$ denote the set $\mathbb R$ equipped with a topology $T.$

Let $S$ be the usual topology on $\mathbb R.$ Let $F$ be the set of continuous $f:\mathbb R_S\to \mathbb R_S.$

For $G\subset F$ let $U_G$ be the set of every topology $T$ on $\mathbb R$ such that $f:\mathbb R_T\to \mathbb R_S$ is continuous for all $f\in G.$

If $id_{\mathbb R}\in G\subset F$ then $v=f^{-1}(v)\in T $ for every $v\in S.$ So  $$id_{\mathbb R}\in G\subset F  \implies \forall T\in U_G\;(T\supset S\in U_G).$$

This holds (verbatim) if we replace $\mathbb R$ with any set $X$, with $S$ being any topology on $X$.